# Python Split List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data set in a data frame:

```
     F   ID S  G     Time              Value
0    1   1  1  4 2018-10-17 14:10:08     11
1    2   1  1  4 2018-10-17 14:10:08     11
2    3   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:11     11
3    4   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:11     11
4    5   1  3  4 2018-10-17 14:10:13     11
5    6   1  4  4 2018-10-17 14:10:16     11
6    7   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:21     16
7    8   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:21     16
8    9   2  2  5 2018-10-17 14:10:23     16
9   10   2  3  5 2018-10-17 14:10:26     16
10  11   3  1  6 2018-10-17 14:10:36     21
11  12   3  1  6 2018-10-17 14:10:36     21
12  13   1  1  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
13  13   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
14  14   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
15  15   1  3  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
16  16   1  4  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
17  17   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:55     16
18  18   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:55     16
```

I want to split up the data into a list of data frames. I want to split it up so that when the "ID" repeats back to 1, it creates a data frame in that list. In this case there should be 2 data frames created:

DF at index 0:

```
0    1   1  1  4 2018-10-17 14:10:08     11
1    2   1  1  4 2018-10-17 14:10:08     11
2    3   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:11     11
3    4   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:11     11
4    5   1  3  4 2018-10-17 14:10:13     11
5    6   1  4  4 2018-10-17 14:10:16     11
6    7   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:21     16
7    8   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:21     16
8    9   2  2  5 2018-10-17 14:10:23     16
9   10   2  3  5 2018-10-17 14:10:26     16
10  11   3  1  6 2018-10-17 14:10:36     21
11  12   3  1  6 2018-10-17 14:10:36     21
```

DF at index 1:

```
13  13   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
14  14   1  2  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
15  15   1  3  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
16  16   1  4  4 2018-10-17 14:10:47     11
17  17   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:55     16
18  18   2  1  5 2018-10-17 14:10:55     16
```

The following snipped of code does not seem to work.

```
list(zip(*df.groupby(df.ID.diff().ne(1).cumsum())))[]
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it!

Comment: Are you expecting the id to repeat multiple times and therefore splits your frame to more than 2?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. I get multiple lists instead of 2.